# Gridview asp:Hyperlink not consistently working

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a problem that my intuition is certain is going to be a really silly detail miss.  But I have a gridview that looks like the following on two different pages.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvFiles" Style="align-items: center; align-self: center"
                                    AutoGenerateColumns="true" runat="server">
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:TemplateField>
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("SerialNumber", "~/GetFile.aspx?ID={0}") %>' Text="Download"></asp:HyperLink>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                    </Columns>
                                </asp:GridView>
```

This generates a link to an asp page that simply creates a download to a file in my database.  It works wonderfully on one page while on the other page it doesn't generate the link properly.

I'll post the code inspection of both below for comparison.

```
<a href="GetFile.aspx?ID=40">Download</a>
```

An example of what the one that works looks like.

```
<a>Download</a>
```

What the one on the other page looks like.

So aside from the link not generating, both gridviews create properly with all of the relevant information, including the id's used to make the link.  So I'm very stumped to say the least.  Can someone identify what might cause this?  I'm not sure what other information or code to include so please let me know if I need to add anything else.  Thanks so much.

EDIT: Adding pictures of gridviews for reference, to demonstrate that they both produce as intended, aside from the fact that the latter doesn't produce links.

[image: This one works]

[image: This one does not]

Edit: I can add my two stored procedures for populating said tables.  The first will be for the working one, the second for the one that isn't.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.LoadFile
@ChangeId INT
AS
BEGIN
SELECT FileName + '.' + FileExtension AS 'File', FileType, ContentType, SerialNumber, Chart
FROM dbo.ChangeFiles
WHERE ChangeId = @ChangeId
END
GO
```

AND

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.LoadPackageFile
@PackageId INT
AS
BEGIN
SELECT FileName + '.' + FileExtension AS 'File', FileType, ContentType, SerialNumber, Chart
FROM dbo.ChangeFiles
WHERE PackageId = @PackageId
END
GO
```

And the methods calling those two stored procedures to populate their respective data tables.

```
public static DataTable GetFileList(int ChangeId) {
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ChangeDb"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr)) {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.LoadFile", con)) {
            try {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ChangeId", ChangeId);
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

                sda.Fill(dt);
            }
            catch (SqlException sqlex) {
                throw new Exception("SQL Exception loading files from database. " + sqlex.Message);
            }

            catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new Exception("Error loading results files from database. " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
    return dt;
}

public static DataTable GetPackageFileList(int PackageId) {
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ChangeDb"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr)) {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.LoadPackageFile", con)) {
            try {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PackageId", PackageId);
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

                sda.Fill(dt);
            }
            catch (SqlException sqlex) {
                throw new Exception("SQL Exception loading files from database. " + sqlex.Message);
            }

            catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new Exception("Error loading results files from database. " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
    return dt;
}
```

FINAL EDIT - FIXED

Hey guys, I ended up fixing the problem by changing it to a simple HTML link, so there was some ASP shenanegans going on.

```
<a href="<%# Eval("SerialNumber", "~/GetFile.aspx?ID={0}") %>">Download</a>
```

Comment: Is this part same in both files : `'<%# Eval("SerialNumber", "~/GetFile.aspx?ID={0}") %>'` ? And do you have SerialNumber property in second form ?

Comment: you have to make sure that SerialNumber Exist in the bound datasource

Comment: The data source isn't defined in your code, so maybe you're passing it to the grid view  from code? If yes, are you sure that they both have the necessary fields? Can you post the data source?

Comment: I added my stored procedures and the methods that call them.  Let me know if that is what you needed.

Comment: @David: did you execute the stored procedures in MS SQL Management Studio to test the output?

Comment: Yeah both work pretty much the exact same aside from requiring different id's.  In the images showing both gridviews, the tables populate with the relevant information, including the Serial numbers that are used to produce the link.

Comment: Have a look at this post: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2006/Apr/27/ASPNET-ItemTemplates-EVAL-and-embedding-dynamic-values-into-controls

Comment: Thank you very much for the link.  I actually changed all asp:hyperlinks to plain html a tags and that fixed my problem.  So there was some ASP shenanigans going on.  I don't understand what happened but I appreciate your help very much in leading me to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
NavigateUrl='<%# "~/GetFile.aspx?ID=" + Eval("SerialNumber", "") %>'
```

Comment: I tried this and unfortunately ran into the same problem.  It worked on the one that already worked, but not on the one that didn't,